# Вопрос по JSP. На jsp странице в цикле c:forEach листается коллекция сущностей товара

Tags: xml, hibernate, java-ee, jsp, spring-mvc

На **JSP** странице в цикле **c:forEach** листается коллекция сущностей товара. Как при каждой итерацации автоматически передавать какое-то значение товара в какой-то другой метод контроллера? По принципу силки, но которая срабатывает автоматически на каждой итерации.
То есть :

```
<c:forEach items="${commodities}" var="commodity">
            // а здесь действие, которое передает автоматически значение ${commodity.id}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Ничего не понял, приведите конкретный пример что должно быть внутри

Comment: <c:forEach items="${commodities}" var="commodity">
          <a href="/cart/commodityOrderDetails/${commodity.id}">Details..</a>
    </c:forEach>

Comment: Зачем это нужно?

Comment: Давайте проще. Мне нужно чтобы в корзине покупателя отображалось количество одинаковых товаров. Может посоветуете как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: Я бы завёл сущность `Purchase` имеющую поле `customer`, ссылающееся на покупателя, поле `commodity`, ссылающееся на товар, и поле `count` хранящее количество этого товара купленного этим пользователем.